# JS adding eventListener to window created variable

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment, addeventlistener

I have some code that loads with the document; adding an event listener for a specific element.  I use this same listener & related functions on a series of pages.  On each page, the specific element is hard code per page needing it, the element is then fed to the listener/functions.

But I need the same listener/functions to apply to several elements on some of those pages.
So I am trying to adapt the code to create page variables on the fly and assigning each element to its own variable and then adding the event listener to each newly created variable.  But its erroring on the `addEventListener` section of my code.

```
//at the top of my document:
<script>
var fileInputIDs = [
     ['ceIcon','ceIconPreview'],
     ['cerImage','cerImagePreview']
] ;
</script>
...
// Page loads, including all the elements with the IDs defined in each fileInputIDs set.
// <input type="file" id="ceIcon">
// <div id="ceIconPreview" width="1200" height="300" style="width:25vw;margin-top:20px;"></div>
...

<script>
// after the document loads, this is at the end:
// create event listeners for each element defined in the array
for (var xx=0;xx<fileInputIDs.length;xx++) {
   window["fileInput_"+xx] = document.getElementById(fileInputIDs[xx][0]) ;
   window["fileInputPreview_"+xx] = document.getElementById(fileInputIDs[xx][1]) ;
 
   window["fileInput_"+xx].addEventListener('change',ev => {  ERROR <= "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')"
      window['fileInputPreview_'+xx].innerHTML = '' ;
      this file = ev.target.files ;
      validateImage(files[0]) ;
   }) ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Then, in at least one iteration of the loop, `window["fileInput_"+xx]` is `undefined`.  When that happens, what is the value of `xx`?  Does that element exist at the time the code runs?  The error suggests that it does not.

Comment: The error is thrown on the first iteration of the loop...adding a `console.log(window['fileInput_'+xx]) ;` does print the proper `<input>` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delegate

Also `this file = ev.target.files;` is invalid JavaScript

```js
const fileInputs = {
  'ceIcon': 'ceIconPreview',
  'cerImage': 'cerImagePreview'
}

document.addEventListener("change", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("[type=file]")) {
    const previewId = fileInputs[tgt.id];
    console.log(previewId)
    // do whatever you need to do with file and preview
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="ceIcon">
<div id="ceIconPreview" width="1200" height="300" style="width:25vw;margin-top:20px;"></div>
```

You do not even need the array if the IDs follows a certain pattern

```js
document.addEventListener("change", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("[type=file]")) {
    const previewId = `${tgt.id}Preview`;
    console.log(previewId)
    // do whatever you need to do with file and preview
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="ceIcon">
<div id="ceIconPreview" width="1200" height="300" style="width:25vw;margin-top:20px;"></div>
```

Comment: I see, you completely changed the logic flow.  Instead of creating unique eventListeners, you are just listening to any `change` in the document, then matching the `change` to input type. I had not considered that.  I will give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you!  Worked well, much cleaner too.  Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to listen from the nearest static element. For example wrap in a div and listen from that

Comment: What would be the purpose/benefit of doing it that way?

Comment: When you delegate, always try to delegate from a relevant and close parent. Because I did not have more information from you, I chose document. If your page is large, the event listener is processing all clicks on the page, in case they were on the file element. So if you have a wrapper for the file elements, use that instead. Like document.getElementById("fileUploadContainer").addEventListener ...